# Why the solution of parabolic Cauchy problem is unique provided that the solution is exponentially bounded?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Why the solution of parabolic Cauchy problem is unique provided that the solution is exponentially bounded? For example, consider the following parabolic equation:
$$u_t-u_{xx}=f(x,t), x\in \mathbb{R}, t\in[0,T]$$ 
$$ u|_{t=0}=\phi(x), x\in \mathbb{R}$$
If the solution of the above Cauchy problem satisfies $$|u(x,t)|\leq C_1  e^{C_2 x^2},\forall x\in \mathbb{R}, t\in[0,T]$$

Then we claim that the solution $u$ is unique.

I have no idea of this problem. Does someone know how to prove it by prior estimate or other methods ?